# Could the extra damage from absorb elements extend over different combat encounters?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[*Absorb elements*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/absorb-elements) says:

> Also, the first time you hit with a melee attack on your next turn, the target takes an extra 1d6 damage of the triggering type, and the spell ends.

If I were to cast *absorb elements* as a reaction after finishing my last turn in a combat encounter, and the combat ended before my next turn, would the extra damage carry over to my first turn in the next combat encounter?

I'm assuming it wouldn’t , but I’m looking for an explanation.

Comment: Related: [Are rounds just for combat, or should we be using them at other times in the game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195530/23547), [When do player characters leave turn-based action (i.e. initiative order) if they are in a hostile area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104614/23547)

Comment: Hola, Pepe and welcome to the stack!  I have taken the liberty of 'sprucing up' your question with some thing we like to see - links to official sources of the rules you are asking about, direct quotes of the specific rules in question, and a detailed statement of your reasoning.  If you do not think these represent what you wanted, you can 'roll back' the edits, or re-edit yourself to keep some and change others.

Comment: When you have a chance, take the site [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) to understand more about what we like to see in questions.  Thanks for a good first question, and happy stacking!

Answer (score 6):

### No - the duration is one round

Even though the spell description states that *absorb elements* ends the first time you hit with a melee attack on **your next turn**, the spell also has an explicit duration of one round.

We know that [a round is](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TheOrderofCombat)

> about six seconds in the game world

Even if your 'next turn' had not come up yet, the spell would end about six seconds after you cast it.  Time continues to pass outside of combat, even if turns are no longer tracked.

Comment: Turns don’t technically exist *ever*, even during combat. They’re just the prescribed way for the players to organize the narrative of the combat the characters are experiencing.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Turns don't exist in a narrative sense, sure, but they very much do in a rules sense.  Since my answer was vague on that point, I have edited it.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that is more clear. Good answer.

Comment: Yes, a turn or a round is simply an abstraction for any period of six seconds: One round passes every six seconds, whether you're in combat or not. We just generally don't keep track of them outside of combat as having to describe tasks taking potentially hours in six second increments would be incredibly cumbersome and boring.